# How warm are radioactive metals?

Tags: temperature, radiation, radioactivity

I read that radium is warm to the touch -- is that because of actual heat or is that because, for example, the radiation it emits creates the sensation of warmth? How high of a temperature can a radioactive element or isotope actually have?

Comment: One source would be Curie, P. and Laborde, A., “Sur la chaleur d´egag´ee spontan´ement par les sels de radium”, Comptes Rendus de l’Acad´emie des Sciences 136, 673–675, session of March 16, 1903, another Rutherford, E. and Soddy, F., “Radioactive Change”, Philosophical Magazine 5, 576–591,
May 1903.

Comment: The classic example is [Plutonium-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238), an alpha emitter with a half-life of 87.7 years. A 5.5 cm ball has a mass ~1.7 kg and puts out over 980 watts. There are numerous images online of balls & pellets of Pu-238 glowing red or orange from their own heat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes radioactive materials are warmer than they would otherwise be. There are two reasons for this.

One is that the decayed atom will have picked up some kinetic energy in recoil and that is heat.

Another is that some of the radiation does not make it outside but hits another atom and transfers its energy to it as more heat. That includes any low-energy photons emitted by the decayed nucleus as it stabilises.

But how hot it gets depends on a variety of factors, such as the half-life, the total energy released in each decay, the concentration or richness of radioactive atoms in the material, the size vs surface area of the lump (the bigger it is, the proportionately less area it has to lose excess heat), and any cooling or insulating effects in its immediate environment.

At one end of the scale, such as a small piece of uranium ore, the heat is not enough to be measurable above background noise. At the other extreme you get a meltdown.

Natural radium is almost entirely radium 226. Its refined form appears to represent a borderline case. The following calculation is off-the-cuff and ignores any impurities, radioactive in themselves or otherwise, somebody please correct any mistakes! Radium 226 has a half-life of 1,600 years. One mole (gramme molecule) weighs 226 g and contains 6 X 10<sup>23</sup> atoms. There are 5 x 10<sup>10</sup> seconds in 1,600 years, so in the mole's first second of existence over 10<sup>13</sup> atoms will decay. Its decay energy is 4.9 MeV, yielding say 4.9 x 10^23 eV or around 10^4 joules, enough to raise the temperature of 226 g of water by 10 degrees or so. The molecular weight of water is 20, so the temperature of the radium will increase by 10 x 20/226 or around 1 deg. That assumes no heat outflow from the radium; its actual temperature rise after an hour will be significantly lower, say 0.5 deg. Note that this is a rise above ambient, it is not an absolute value. Given a human hand several degrees warmer, and you may find that material properties like thermal conductivity may distort your subjective sense of warmth to the touch.

Comment: the half life means some portion of it is no longer radium. so it makes sense i think to speak of pure radium. then i guess how much would affect the heat since it interacts with itself -- a bigger chunk might be warmer per gram than a smaller chunk. also shape would matter. so can one calculate roughly how warm a sphere weighing a gram of pure radium or any other radioactive element would be?

Comment: A chunk of pure radium would be at whatever temperature it was formed at - because a second later it is not pure radium any more. The current state of the alloy is covered by my remark about "the concentration or richness of radioactive atoms in the material". But natural radium 226 has a half-life of over 1,000 years so it comes at the in-the-noise-floor end of the spectrum. Other, more transient isotopes would be hotter, in both senses of the word.

Answer (score 4):

The interesting number for application in [radioisotope thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) is the power by weight. It is not very high for radium, as the half-life is 1600 years. The Pioneers use generators containing 13 kg of $^{238}$Pu with a halflife of 88 years. That has a power density of 0.54 W/g.

The linked wikipedia article says: "A half-gram sample of $^{210}$Po reaches temperatures of over 500 °C." ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120310145431/http://www.ead.anl.gov/pub/doc/polonium.pdf) at Argonne Laboratory).

Comment: That's a heck of a thing: something that is naturally hot enough to start not just wood but other materials on fire. Po has a strange reputation for, for example, moving against air currents: wouldn't this heat account for that potentially? I am going to make a new question about this.

Answer (score 3):

Subcritical chunks of enriched uranium and plutonium are naturally warm to the touch, because of the thermal energy released as they spontaneously fission. Plutonium has a higher spontaneous fission rate and this effect is stronger for Pu.

If you place two such subcritical chunks near one another and slide them together gradually, at some point the neutrons released by one will induce extra fissions in the other, and the resulting energy release will make their facing sides hot enough to glow red.

Such (incredibly unsafe!) demonstrations and experiments were done at research laboratories like Los Alamos during the Manhattan Project. Two people died at Los Alamos due to radiation exposure when they slipped up while moving the chunks around. Don't do this at home!

Comment: Indeed.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core

Comment: That demon core thing has well made it into popular culture (Dr. Manhattan's origin story echoes the demon core event). Just a horrifying event but  of course other horrifying things have happened -- I think the case of the salvage workers in Brasil who broke open (which took some doing) the cesium capsule from a radiation therapy machine experienced a similar if slower horror.

Comment: @releseabe They weren't salvage workes, they were looters. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goi%C3%A2nia_accident